# Jquery password strength library not defined

Tags: jquery, html, css, passwords

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/shevabam/jquery.passwordstrength) to implement password strength feedback on my website.

The problem is that I can't read the jQuery function defined in the JS file. I already tried everything and it still doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery :: Password Strength</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.passwordstrength.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/jquery.passwordstrength.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    form>section {
      position: relative;
    }

    input#pwd {
      width: 200px;
      padding: 3px;
      color: #000;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input#pwd').passwordstrength({
        'minlength': 6,
        'number': true,
        'capital': true,
        'special': true,
        'labels': {
          'general': 'Le mot de passe doit avoir :',
          'minlength': 'Au moins {{minlength}} caractères',
          'number': 'Au moins un chiffre',
          'capital': 'Au moins une lettre majuscule',
          'special': 'Au moins un caractère spécial'
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <section>
      <label>Your password :</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" />
    </section>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Image of what i want to have on my page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG5KL.jpg

```
Index:67 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).passwordstrength is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:67)
at fire (jquery-latest.js:3119)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.js:3231)
at Function.ready (jquery-latest.js:3443)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-latest.js:3474)
```

Comment: The error means that the path `~/Scripts/jquery.passwordstrength.js` is not correct and the JS file isn't being loaded. You just need to fix the path.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to include the entire CSS and JS of the library in the question. I've removed them

Comment: [link] https://i.imgur.com/pRqEUaG.png?1 Rory can you watch the print and tell me what path should i use then

Comment: It's not clear form that image as you don't show where in your routing structure the Index action sits. But as a rule of thumb, make the URLs relative to the site root: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.passwordstrength.js")"></script>`